# Getting URL parameters by using FastAPI

Tags: fastapi, url-parameters

I want to create an API using FastAPI that takes url from user and takes just url as a parameter. For example,localhost:8000/tansu?url=www.google.com is my url and I wanted only 'url=www.google.com' part. On fastAPI tutorials I can take parameters from url but they are specific urls how can I do for random urls from user. Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

```
use fastapi "query" parameters.
```

for further infos visit : [doc](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/)

```
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/{user}")
async def read_item(user: str, url: Optional[str] = None):
    if url:
        return {"user": user, "url": url}
    return {"user": user}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use query parameters

> main.py

```py
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/tansu")
async def get_url(
    url: str = None
):
    return {"url": url}
```

Now, run the dev server and access http://localhost:8000/tansu?url=www.google.com

You will see below response.

```json
{"url": "www.google.com"}
```

Reference: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the request parameter, and then take a lot of things from there, including all of the url parameters:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/tansu")
async def tansu(request : Request):
  url = request.query_params.get('url', None)
  return {'url' : url}
```